# How to open vim buffer next to current buffer rather than at the end

Tags: vim

I don't use tabs in in vim, I just use buffers and buffer switching, but I have a real pickle. I can't figure out how to open a new buffer next to this one, so that when I switch buffers I don't have to switch all the way to the end. Many times I'm opening files for reference.

Let's say I have five buffers open

[0][1][2][3][4]

And I'm working on the second

[0]**[1]**[2][3][4]

I'd like to open a new buffer here:

[0]**[1]**[new buffer][2][3][4]

Rather than here:

[0]**[1]**[2][3][4][new buffer]

Make sense?

Comment: Nope I don't want to use 'order of activity' That would be unlimitedly confusing.

Comment: It's a similar situation, in that it's very difficult to reorder buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the ordering and insertion of buffers, you have to use the *argument list* instead. The buffer numbers increase steadily and are fixed; there's no way to shuffle them around.

So, use `:argedit` to open another file; it will be placed just after the current entry. You can control the positioning via the optional `[count]`. As a bonus, the `:next` / `:n` command is one character shorter than `:bnext` / `:bn`.